# Sum of elements in a diagonal

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the matrix

```
 MatrixForm[A = {{8, 1, 6}, {3, 5, 7}, {4, 9, 2}}]
```

with `Tr[A]` I can sum the elements of the main diagonal. To sum the elements of the opposite diagonal, which runs from upper right to lower left I type

```
Tr[Reverse[A]]
```

How can I obtain the desired result differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First I thought "Why would you want to do that?" but using `Reverse` has indeed some performance issues. Here is an alternative involving `Extract` and `Total`:

```
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10000, 10000}];
a = Tr[Reverse[A]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Total[Extract[A, Transpose[{Range[Length[A]], Range[Length[A], 1, -1]}]]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b
```

> 0.487564
>
> 0.000616
>
> True